# Moved a directory with mv command and the target is empty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mv

I am trying to move the contents of a directory with the `mv` command in Ubuntu.

I made a mistake, and ran this command:

```
mv BackupBases/ /home/developer/BackupBases/
```

without the asterisk `*` that should have been at the end of the first argument.

Now I see that `/home/developer/BackupBases/BackupBases` is an empty directory.

Is there any way to recover what existed in `BackupBases`???

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Your command should not have destroyed any data. If there were any contents in the original directory, they would be in the created one, unless something weird is going on.

Comment: Did you interrupt the command while it was running? Do you know for a fact that the source directory contained files?